# React Native - Erro ao emular Android

Tags: android, react-native, emulador

Estou tentando emular um app e aparece este erro impedindo que prossiga com o trabalho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um Win 10 64 bits JDK 9.0.1 NodeJS 6.11.4

Comment: Esse erro está dizendo que você precisa estar *Emulador do Android* aberto ou um *Celular conectado* para poder testar o *App*.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém este erro aparece mesmo com o emulador ou o celular conectado. Eu havia fechado o Android Studio e tirei o print da tela, por isso não tem ele.

Comment: Veja na sessão [Android development environment](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment) da documentação sobre configuração do ambiente de desenvolvimento *Android*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com https://stackoverflow.com/a/46415922/1650128, o erro está relacionado à versão do JDK: recomenda-se JDK 8, enquanto você está utilizando o JDK 9.